# czmq asynchronous send/receive (PUB/SUB)

Tags: c++, ipc, zeromq

I'm using czmq for interprocess communication.

There are 2 processes :

- The server, receiving requests and sending replies but also sending events.
- The client, sending requests and receiving replies but also listening to the events.

I have already successfuly implemented the "request/reply" pattern with REQ/REP (details below)

Now I want to implement the notification mechanism.
I want my server to send its events without caring whether anyone receives them or not and without being blocked in anyway.
The client listens to those events but should it crash, it mustn't have any impact on the server.
I believe PUB/SUB is the most appropriate pattern, but if not do not hesitate to enlighten me.

Here's my implementation (cleaned from checks and logs) :

The server publishes the events

```
Server::eventIpcPublisher = zsock_new_pub("@ipc:///tmp/events.ipc");

void Server::OnEvent(uint8_t8* eventData, size_t dataSize) {
  if (Server::eventIpcPublisher != nullptr) {
    int retCode = zsock_send(Server::eventIpcPublisher, "b", eventData, dataSize);
}
```

The client listens to them in a dedicated thread

```
void Client::RegisterToEvents(const std::function<void(uint8_t*, size_t)>& callback) {
  zsock_t* eventIpcSubscriber = zsock_new_sub(">ipc:///tmp/events.ipc", "");
  listening = true;
  while (listening) {
    byte* receptionBuffer;
    size_t receptionBufferSize;
    int retCode = zsock_recv(eventIpcSubscriber, "b", &receptionBuffer, &receptionBufferSize);
    --> NEVER REACHED <--
    if (retCode == 0) {
      callback(static_cast<uint8_t*>(receptionBuffer), receptionBufferSize);
    }
  }
  zsock_destroy(&eventIpcSubscriber);
}
```

It doesn't work:

- The server sends with return code 0, as if everything is ok,
- The client doesn't receive anything (blocked on receive).

Help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Chris.

PS: here is the REQ/REP that I have already implemented with success (no help needed here, just for comprehension)

The client sends a request and then waits for the answer.

```
uint8_t* MulticamApi::GetDatabase(size_t& sizeOfData) {
  zsock_t* requestSocket = zsock_new_req(">ipc:///tmp/requests.ipc");
  if (requestSocket == nullptr)
    return nullptr;
  byte* receptionBuffer;
  size_t receptionBufferSize;
  int retCode = zsock_send(requestSocket, "i", static_cast<int>(IpcComm_GetClipDbRequest));
  if (retCode != 0) {
    sizeOfData = 0;
    return nullptr;
  }
  retCode = zsock_recv(requestSocket, "b", &receptionBuffer, &receptionBufferSize);
  databaseData.reset(new MallocGuard(static_cast<void*>(receptionBuffer)));
  sizeOfData = receptionBufferSize;
  return static_cast<uint8_t*>(databaseData->Data());
}
```

A dedicated thread in the server listens to requests, processes them and replies. (don't worry, delete is handled somewhere else)

```
U32 Server::V_OnProcessing(U32 waitCode) {
  protocolIpcWriter = zsock_new_rep("@ipc:///tmp/requests.ipc");
  while (running) {
    int receptionInt = 0;
    int retCode = zsock_recv(protocolIpcWriter, "i", &receptionInt);
    if ((retCode == 0) && (receptionInt == static_cast<int>(IpcComm_GetClipDbRequest))) {
      GetDatabase();
    }
    sleep(1);
  }
  zsock_destroy(&protocolIpcWriter);
  return 0;
}

void Server::GetDatabase() {
  uint32_t dataSize = 10820 * 340;
  uint8_t* data = new uint8_t[dataSize];
  uint32_t nbBytesWritten = DbHelper::SaveDbToBuffer(data, dataSize);
  int retCode = zsock_send(protocolIpcWriter, "b", data, nbBytesWritten);
}
```

Comment: I have tried the 4 combinations between  "start pub first" / "start sub first" and "@pub, >sub" / ">pub, @sub", none of them works...

Comment: It's hard to tell from your code - is there a delay between binding on the `PUB` & connecting with the `SUB`, and then sending the first message? [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32481573/545332) for why this is important. If your timing is otherwise correct and your subscriber has finished connecting before you publish your message that goes missing, then for troubleshooting purposes I would write a pub/sub example that is a little more straight forward, use TCP instead of IPC (even if it's on the same host) and just do a straight publish in a loop to see it work.

Comment: Hi Jason and thank you for your answer!
It's not an issue about missing the first few messages - it doesn't matter - it's that I receive no message at all.
I have tried creating the either the publisher or the subscriber first, with no success. The publisher sends events on a regular basis and the subscriber receives nothing, event after a long time (minutes). I'll try with TCP instead of IPC and keep you posted.

Comment: Question, is eventIpcSubscriber a valid pointer after zsock_t* eventIpcSubscriber = zsock_new_sub(">ipc:///tmp/events.ipc", "");

My suspicion is that you are getting a null socket back.

Comment: Hello atifm and thanks for your comment. For reading clarity purpose, I had put the minimum amount of code required to expose the issue but in fact, I had the zmq recommended asserts: assert(eventIpcSubscriber != nullptr);  assert(zsock_resolve(eventIpcSubscriber) != eventIpcSubscriber);  assert(streq(zsock_type_str(eventIpcSubscriber), "SUB")); Same for the publisher. So the socket handles are valid, it's not the source of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know my question's old but for the record, I switched from `czmq` to base `zmq` api and everything went smooth. A colleague of mine also had issues with the `czmq` layer and switched to `zmq` to fix them so that's definitely what I recommend.